# Struts 2.3 error: Unable to load configuration and similar errors

Tags: java, eclipse, struts2

Just started to learn struts 2.x and setup the project in eclipse, i have referred some tutorials site and struts documentation, but while i try to run a simple HelloWorld application. I get resource Not found error in browser.
Here is the console output of what is going wrong.

```
Jul 04, 2014 5:13:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin;C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-2.1.6\bin;C:\Python33;G:\python\work;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Hewlett-Packard\HP ProtectTools Security Manager\Bin\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\RailsInstaller\Git\cmd;C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Bitvise SSH Client;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin;.
Jul 04, 2014 5:13:57 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:StrutsDemo' did not find a matching property.
Jul 04, 2014 5:13:57 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jul 04, 2014 5:13:57 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jul 04, 2014 5:13:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 688 ms
Jul 04, 2014 5:13:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jul 04, 2014 5:13:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.32
Jul 04, 2014 5:14:01 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider info
INFO: Parsing configuration file [struts-default.xml]
Jul 04, 2014 5:14:01 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider info
INFO: Parsing configuration file [struts-plugin.xml]
Jul 04, 2014 5:14:01 PM org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher error
SEVERE: Dispatcher initialization failed
Unable to load configuration. - bean - jar:file:/G:/eclipse/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/StrutsDemo/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-gxp-plugin-2.3.16.3.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:8:162
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:70)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:445)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:489)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:74)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:277)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:382)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5306)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: Unable to load bean: type:org.apache.struts2.views.gxp.inject.InjectedObjectContainer class:org.apache.struts2.views.gxp.inject.InjectedObjectContainer - bean - jar:file:/G:/eclipse/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/StrutsDemo/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-gxp-plugin-2.3.16.3.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:8:162
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:245)
    at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.register(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:102)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:234)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:67)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts2.views.gxp.inject.InjectedObjectContainer
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.ClassLoaderUtil.loadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.java:152)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:216)
    ... 21 more

Jul 04, 2014 5:14:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2
Unable to load configuration. - bean - jar:file:/G:/eclipse/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/StrutsDemo/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-gxp-plugin-2.3.16.3.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:8:162
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:501)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:74)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:277)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:382)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5306)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: Unable to load configuration. - bean - jar:file:/G:/eclipse/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/StrutsDemo/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-gxp-plugin-2.3.16.3.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:8:162
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:70)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:445)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:489)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: Unable to load bean: type:org.apache.struts2.views.gxp.inject.InjectedObjectContainer class:org.apache.struts2.views.gxp.inject.InjectedObjectContainer - bean - jar:file:/G:/eclipse/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/StrutsDemo/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-gxp-plugin-2.3.16.3.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:8:162
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:245)
    at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.register(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:102)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:234)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:67)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts2.views.gxp.inject.InjectedObjectContainer
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.ClassLoaderUtil.loadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.java:152)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:216)
    ... 21 more

Jul 04, 2014 5:14:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error filterStart
Jul 04, 2014 5:14:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/StrutsDemo] startup failed due to previous errors
Jul 04, 2014 5:14:01 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jul 04, 2014 5:14:01 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jul 04, 2014 5:14:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 3917 ms
```

Comment: Remove `struts2-gxp-plugin`.

Comment: i did but no success. still not able to run it.

Comment: Post new exception stacktrace.

Comment: its now showing the same kind of exception but this time its struts2-portlet-plugin-2.3.16.3.jar , it will be more clear if you state the reason behind these exception??

Comment: Reason? You have plugins that you are not using. Remove them from your application.

Comment: Are you using portlet enviornment? or Are you using @inject somewhere in your code?

Comment: I have removed the jars you asked for, even then now i am encountered with the problems showing jars related to spring?!

Comment: Parth i don't know about it, i have just started learning it by my own.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22617924/573032

Answer (score 0):

Include only those libraries which you required in your project . 
Basic Struts lib required .
commons-fileupload-x.y.z.jar

commons-io-x.y.z.jar

commons-lang-x.y.jar

commons-logging-x.y.z.jar

commons-logging-api-x.y.jar

freemarker-x.y.z.jar

javassist-.xy.z.GA

ognl-x.y.z.jar

struts2-core-x.y.z.jar

xwork-core.x.y.z.jar

these are basic else you can add as you require in your project , remove all unwanted libraries